# fullscreen uiview not worked perfectly

Tags: xcode, uiview, autolayout, resize

good morning,
i have a problem when i tried to pass to a full screen by clicking on the zoom button.In fact when i tapped the button displays a video and a toolbar that allows to move in the video. it's seems worked perfectly but i discovered that when I move through the slider to a level almost 60% I can not move forward or backward.
i think that the problem is due to layout setting.
this the code :

```
- (void)changeFullScreen:(BOOL)isFullScreen index:(int)index{
if (isFullScreen == YES) {

    CGAffineTransform affineTransforme = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
    //CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height / [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    //affineTransforme = CGAffineTransformScale(affineTransforme,scale , scale);

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:index inSection:0];
    EMPOIVideoCell *cell = [poiTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    tmpVideoPlayerview = [cell.containerView viewWithTag:101];
    //tmpVideoPlayerview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    tmpVideoPlayerview.transform = affineTransforme;  //CGAffineTransformTranslate(affineTransforme, 190, 0);

    fullScreenView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    tmpVideoPlayerview.frame = CGRectMake(-248, 0, fullScreenView.view.bounds.size.height , fullScreenView.view.bounds.size.width);
    tmpVideoPlayerview.videoContainer.frame = tmpVideoPlayerview.frame;

    tmpVideoPlayerview.videoContainer.layer.frame = tmpVideoPlayerview.frame;

    playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:tmpVideoPlayerview.videoPlayer];
    playerLayer.frame = tmpVideoPlayerview.videoContainer.bounds;
    [tmpVideoPlayerview.avPlayerLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    [tmpVideoPlayerview.videoContainer.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
    tmpVideoPlayerview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    //[tmpVideoPlayerview updateConstraints];
    [tmpVideoPlayerview setNeedsLayout] ;
    [tmpVideoPlayerview layoutIfNeeded];
    fullScreenView.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [fullScreenView.view addSubview:tmpVideoPlayerview];
    [self addChildViewController:fullScreenView];
    [self.view addSubview:fullScreenView.view];
    //[fullScreenView.view updateConstraints];
    //[fullScreenView.view layoutIfNeeded];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

}
```

[photo to explain the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4YMZ.png)

Comment: any idea please

Comment: please any idea the problem is that the tmpVideoPlayerview doesn't fit the superview fullScreenView. I can't understand why!!!!